# @ngrx won't allow me to retrieve duplicate values

Tags: angular, state, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I'm using @ngrx/store and everything works great as long as don't purposefully re-enter the same value into state.  When I do, my subscribers aren't notified that a new value was put onto the observable stream.  For instance, maybe I want to submit a text message to a component that will display a dialog.  Problem is, what if the message is the same as the last message?  The dialog never gets displayed because distintUntilChanged is baked into the @ngrx select function.  I've tried using .map instead of .select but when I do that, my subscriber gets notified every time there is a change in state even if it's something unrelated like router state.  Anyone know of a possible solution?  This seems like a super basic function a lot of people would need.  Please help.

Comment: use `pluck` if you want to keep using hardcoded string like you did with `select`

Comment: I've spent 2 days on this trying different peoples suggestions (from gitter.im).  Just now I got it working by adding another property to my state that I toggle (true,false).  I toggle the true/false within the same reducer function that sets my dialog string.  I `.combineLatest` this new boolean property with the previous string property i'm trying to grab from state, so now my dialog box properly pops up when it should.  Not the best approach but at least it's working.

Comment: `pluck` should so the very same as `select` just without the `distinct`-part - but anyways, I'd say your architecture is not 100% optimal - since the UI should only display the state, the _correct_ way would be to set the message-state to `null` or `undefined` to hide the message, this will also solve the issue that you don't receive a new message - in case you want to use your displayed message like an "event" through your app, I would not use the ngrx/store for this, since it is a _store_ and not a _message-bus_

Comment: I can't figure out how to use pluck in a way that allows me to get this working.  If someone has an example way to use it, plz post.

Comment: I used your suggestion of setting to null.  First my reducer sets the new message to be displayed in the dialog and so the dialog displays it, at the same time the effects file sets it to null so it's ready for the next message.  From what I understand, the effects happen after reducer functions so this works perfectly and is in fact working for me.

Comment: this.store.pluck('YourreducerName').subscribe(x => console.log(x)) but u will get huge amount of calls.